# Why do these Random seeds print 'Hello World'?

Tags: ruby, tree, random-seed

Using these random seed values generates `'Hello Word'`, but why?

```
seeds = [685_995_739, 811_060_588]

tree = seeds.map do |seed|
    srand seed
    leafs = leaf = '' # seed grow, become leaf
    leafs += (leaf + 64).chr while (leaf = rand(27)) > 0
    next leafs
end

puts tree.join ' ' # Seed become tree =D
```

Comment: Because that's how Ruby's RNG is implemented?

Comment: Because if you seed the particular random-number algorithm that Ruby uses with that particular seed, you happen to get "Hello World"?  I'm not sure there's much more to it than that...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for [`srand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-srand), those seeds are the ones for which `rand(27)` will choose the sequence of numbers representing "Hello" and "World", ending with "0" to "indicate the end".

```
irb(main):042:0> srand 685_995_739
=> 0
irb(main):043:0> rand 27
=> 8
irb(main):044:0> rand 27
=> 5
irb(main):045:0> rand 27
=> 12
irb(main):046:0> rand 27
=> 12
irb(main):047:0> rand 27
=> 15
irb(main):048:0> rand 27
=> 0
irb(main):049:0> [8,5,12,12,15].map{ |n| (n+64).chr }
=> ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"]
```

Left as an exercise to the reader: write a script that finds the right seed for a given resulting string, that runs in a decent time ;o)

Comment: Cool. For anyone else reading this, this is why you should avoid use generic rand() - from any language - to directly generate security keys (such as session codes or special offer codes). Often the randomiser's state can be determined from one example, and that can be fed to an srand function and further valid codes generated from it.

Comment: Exactly. If you *are* looking to generate random numbers, take a look at StdLib's [SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html).